# How to link standard headers to source code?

Tags: c++, c, clion

I'm used to Intellij'IDEA where I can browse the source code of any class part of the JDK and display the Javadoc with Ctrl+J.

Is there any equivalent in CLion for C/C++?
I can get from a function to its definition in the header file, but is it possible to get from the header function definition to the actual source code implementation on my platform?

In the same line, there must be some comment in the implementation, is it possible to directly display it?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ decompiles the class. The result is somewhat usable.

Disassembled C++ is not very useful in most cases. And Comments are not part of the compiled binary.

If you want to be able to jump from the definition in a header file to the source, you have to add the source code to your project.

Comment: I'm not talking about decompiled class but about linking the source code in the IDE and having CLion being able to contextually lead me to it and possibly displaying the formatted comment in the context without going to the source code, just like IDEA can do. So my question is how do you link the sources? Menu 'View-> Jump to source' just go to headers, not to the implementation of the header function

Answer (score 0):

`F1` or `View->Quick Documentation` does display contextually the `BSD Library Functions Manual` which is exactly what I needed.

I'm still looking for a way to link the headers implementation source code in CLion.